# http error 500 when using amasty social login Magento2

Tags: magento2, amasty

I am facing a problem with a Magento extension that handles social media login, it is returning http 500 error upon registration, below is the error log returned by Nginx.
If anyone can help me solve this issue it would be great.

Magento version ver. 2.3.0

Nginx Error log

```
"2021/10/20 07:10:22 [error] 631864#631864: *320220 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRequest() on null in /var/www/magento/app/code/BulkGate/Magesms/Observer/CustomerRegisterSuccessObserver.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72): BulkGate\Magesms\Observer\CustomerRegisterSuccessObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(BulkGate\Magesms\Observer\CustomerRegisterSuccessObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#2 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#3 /var/www/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('customer_regist...', Array)
#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/Amasty/Soci" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.176.208.13, server: , request: "GET /amsociallogin/social/login/?state=HA-RMQ1873PWNCD0G5BJLSTFU6O4AYI92ZXEKVH&code=4%2F0AX4XfWhCSy-B0mhltFedpnr17NAWVYGY9aTw3HAJ6EGomZVplVmUJM_WkkkzIORWBdWPgw&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm-www.sock:", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://accounts.google.com/""
```

Comment: Your BulkGate Magesms module is failing for some reason. Look in the file the error mentions and update the question if necessary

Comment: You can ask for support from the amasty team, and send screenshots or proof of the issue you are facing they will surely help you, you can start by contacting them.